# Convert seconds to readable format time

Tags: python, time

I have variable that has seconds and I want to convert to detailed time format. I have like this at the moment.

```
runTime = '%s Hours:Minutes:Seconds' % time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(runTime))
```

Outputs:

```
17:25:46 Hours:Minutes:Seconds
```

I would like to have it formated as such:

```
 17 Hours 25 Minutes 46 Seconds
```

Ultimately I would like to be able shorten for smaller values:

So if the value is minutes and seconds it would like like

```
15 Minutes 5 Seconds
```

and if has more then 24 hours then days

```
  1 Days 15 Hours 5 Minutes 1 Seconds
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 9):

You should use the excellent [`dateutil` package](https://labix.org/python-dateutil) and then your task becomes trivial:

```
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta as rd
>>> fmt = '{0.days} days {0.hours} hours {0.minutes} minutes {0.seconds} seconds'
>>> print(fmt.format(rd(seconds=62745)))
0 days 17 hours 25 minutes 45 seconds
```

A bit of an advanced example, which only shows values for those fields that are non-zero:

```
>>> intervals = ['days','hours','minutes','seconds']
>>> x = rd(seconds=12345)
>>> print(' '.join('{} {}'.format(getattr(x,k),k) for k in intervals if getattr(x,k)))
3 hours 25 minutes 45 seconds
>>> x = rd(seconds=1234432)
>>> print(' '.join('{} {}'.format(getattr(x,k),k) for k in intervals if getattr(x,k)))
14 days 6 hours 53 minutes 52 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this step by step, first determining the days/hours, then adding the minutes/seconds.

```
import time

current_time = time.gmtime()   # Or whatever time.
hours = int(time.strftime("%H", current_time))
days = hours / 24
hours = hours % 24

time_string = ""
if days > 0:
  time_string += "%d Days " % days
if hours > 0:
  time_string += "%d Hours " % hours

time_string += time.strftime("%M Minutes %S Seconds", current_time)
```

You can place the extra words directly into `time.strftime`'s first argument. The `%H:%M:%S` isn't a required format; it's much more like string formatting, where you can add words wherever and have the arguments appear where you want.